# Wrapping useState hook with custom setter and clean-up functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to create a custom React hook that

1. wraps a state (created with `useState`),
2. runs a clean-up function up when the component unmounts,
3. executes a custom setter logic that derives a value,
4. and exports the custom setter and the internal state value.

```js
export function useCustomState() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // do cleanup
    };
  }, [value]);

  function customSetValue(newValue) {
    if (value) {
      // do cleanup for the previous value
    }

    const derivedValue = derive(newValue);
    setValue(derivedValue);
  }

  return [value, customSetValue];
}
```

I can achieve this with the code above. My problem arises when I use the returned values in an `useEffect` hook as a dependency, since the returned custom setter is always a new function reference.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useCustomState();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setValue(simpleValue);
    },
    [setValue],
  );

  return <p>{ value }</p>;
};
```

When I don't include the setter as a dependency of the `useEffect`, the re-rendering stops, since the dependency does not change after a render. I can omit that reference and disable eslint for the line. This is one solution.

**I'd like to know whether it is possible to create a custom referentially stable setter function?**

I also have tried using `useMemo` that stores the custom setter function, but the dependencies for the memo still include the internal `value` and `setValue` references, since I want to do clean-up and set the new derived value. If the derived value is not the same for the same input, the dependency cycle will result in infinite re-rendering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a function to `setValue` to remove the dependence on `value`; instead, the current value is passed as an argument.  As a simpler alternative to `useMemo`, `useCallback` will give you a consistent function:

```js
export function useCustomState() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // do cleanup
    };
  }, [value]);

  const customSetValue = useCallback((newValue) => {
    setValue((oldValue) => {
      if (oldValue) {
        // do cleanup for the previous value
      }
      const derivedValue = derive(newValue);
      return derivedValue;
    });
  }, []);

  return [value, customSetValue];
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Also: is the cleanup needed in the setter, or the does the `useEffect` cleanup do that as well?

Comment: I guess it depends what kind of cleanup you're doing, and when you want it to happen.  The cleanup inside `setValue` lets you do cleanup before `value` changes.  The cleanup in `useEffect` lets you do cleanup afterward, and lets you do cleanup just before the component unmounts.

Comment: I just want to make sure that any object reference that is calculated in the custom setter is eventually freed, when the component is unmounted. If useEffect will clean-up every value that is set, I'm happy with it.

Comment: Yes, `useEffect` should do what you want, so that'll make even simpler code. Hmm, unless perhaps you did multiple `setValue` calls within the same callback; I'm not sure whether those would coalesce into a single `useEffect` call.